# Switch library based on minSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-manifest

On my current Android app, the minimum SDK version is 19. I use a library lets call it as "XYZ.jar".
The minimum compatible version of library is also 19. It works perfectly fine.

Now I have a requirement that my app should support Android 4.1.1 which is of sdkversion 16.
When I changed the minimum SDK version in the app to 16 and when I build it, I get the following error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [XXX_Android_v2.0:XXXLibrary:unspecified] XXPATHXX\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\XXX_Android_v2.0\XXXLibrary\unspecified\AndroidManifest.xml]
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.xxx.xxx.api3" to force usage

I have one more library lets call it as "ABC" which has an miniumum sdk version 14. So what i need to acheive is when the sdkversion is less than 19 
use library ABC and when the sdk version is more than 19 use the liberabry XYZ. How do i acheive this while building my project ?

Comment: why do you need this? Your app can have only 1 minSdk value

Comment: I have a requirement to support android 4.1.1 so i need to use an different library that has a different minSDKVersion